# Intellij multi-module maven project, update in one of the submodules is not propagated to war

Tags: scala, maven, jar, intellij-idea, war

I'm using Intellij Idea 12 and have a multi module maven project.

To make it simple let's assume that I have:

- Module A - compiled to JAR
- Module B - depending on module A and also compiled to JAR
- Module C - depending on module B, but compiled to WAR

I know Intellij has it's own build mechanism for maven projects so when I build a WAR for the first time and deploy it to Tomcat generally all works as it should. The problem start when you need to make changes in one of the sub modules, for example Module A and rebuild the War (rebuild Module C)

Intellij as it seems uses the old Module A jar that was previously build and ignores any changes I made in Module A when making/building Module C.

The only way I found to solve this is to run a Maven build on Module A and B and initiallly build the WAR with Maven and deploy it as external source.

The problem is that I have 10 WARs I want to deploy and more then 20 sub modules that compiled to jars. It doesn't make sense to rebuild all wars when I'm only want to see the changes I made in one of sub modules that affects one WAR. And sure doesn't make sense to build them externally with command line while paying for Intellij Ultimate license (so I can work with Application servers)

Now comparing this behavior to other IDE
1. Netbeans works with maven projects naturally via Maven and all builds/deployments and such are done with Maven and not by some internal mechanism.
2. Eclipse does the same with it's internal mechanism but all JARs are updated when WAR project are rebuild. (Or some other magic that works)

Is there a way work differently with IDEA or there isn't ?

Comment: Please post this on Intellij Idea JIRA tracker.

Comment: "Make Project Automatically" is enabled in your IDEA?

Comment: Posted on Intellij Youtrack - http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-106162

Comment: Also this is a mixed Java/Scala project so I can't turn on automatic make or parallel compilation since it's not supported by Idea

Comment: @TalG. why do you think this works for NetBeans? It looks like only 7.4 will improve this 'multi-module-compile-on-save' http://forums.netbeans.org/topic54949.html

Comment: Netbeans uses maven and not internal compiler/builder to run the WAR on Tomcat. It packs the WAR with Maven and then deploys it via MANAGER application (I think). This is differently than IDEA since it builds and packs the WAR itself and if you use Maven's artifacts you loose hot deployment of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I found a hybrid solution for this:
Things to be done before Tomcat is run:

1. Clean all
2. Build, package and register (in repository) all projects that should become JAR
3. Compile only (Don't build) WAR projects
4. Build WAR artifacts with Intellij (This is needed for hot swap availability)

This is how I start Tomcat.

Detailed information:

1. Create 3 Maven run configurations

   1.1 **Clean** all projects [image: Maven Clean for all Projects]
   1.2 **Build** all projects with JAR artifacts. You need to manually include all your projects with the '-pl' maven option. Optionally you can run "Maven clean" before launch of this configuration (look at screenshot) [image: Build Jars]
   1.3 **Compile** all Projects with WAR artifacts - **No packaging with Maven**[image: Compile WARs]
2. Create Tomcat configuration to Build War artifacts and include other configurations to run before Launch [image]

Now when Tomcat is run it is possible to hotswap code changes (if JVM allows) or simply restart server to include all your new code/changes. The draw back of this is somewhat longer start time of Tomcat. That's something we are willing to live with..... For now

Answer (score 0):

I think hot code deployment works only with exploded artifacts. In IDEA 11 I rename the exploded directory, because the maven artefacts is at the same location and the name is same.

Comment: Hot deployment is yet a dream for me :)
I have "update" problems even when I want to redeploy my war to tomcat.

Comment: What are you deploying? Exploded or external artefacts?

Comment: Wars generated by Intellij Idea, this is what I want to deploy

Comment: It seems this one is related to new external compilation introduced in IDEA 12. If I disable external build in Compiler settings I can see host swaps class updates. I'll keep testing and if this one is the case I'll publish the anwser with screenshots